# Prism Library UWP Show multiple views for an app

Tags: uwp, prism, prism-4

I am trying [Show multiple views for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views) for Prism Library UWP.

I got `System.NullReferenceException` for `frame.Navigate(typeof(ScreenCapture));` like below:

```
        async void ExecuteNewWindow()
        {
            CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
            int newViewId = 0;
            await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Frame frame = new Frame();
                frame.Navigate(typeof(ScreenCapture));
                Window.Current.Content = frame;
                // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
                Window.Current.Activate();

                newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
            });
            bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
        }
```

How to implement multiple view in Prism library for uwp.

Comment: It's very strange, I run above code, but I could not reproduce your issue again. Could you share a code sample that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: And the app's target and min version are 1903 1809, the os version is 1909.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT For this issue, I am using Prism library framework. Do you test with prism?

Comment: Yep, I create sample with Template Studio and add Prism lib, It works well.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Please check this reproduce [project](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/IssueTest.git)

Comment: You could not call `frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));` in the forms project, the `MainPage`  is not uwp page.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Do you mean open new window did not work for xamarian.uwp ?

Comment: You could call it in uwp native project, but your  MainPage is forms content page but not uwp page.

Comment: For your requirement we suggest use dependency service call   `ExecuteNewWindow` and place current above method in uwp client project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is Xamarin.Forms, but the parameter of  `frame.Navigate(typeof(ScreenCapture));` is uwp Page type. I checked your code, `ScreenCapture` is Forms `ContentPage`. For your requirement, you could use [Dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/registration-and-resolution) to call  `ExecuteNewWindow` and place `ExecuteNewWindow` in UWP project.

**Interface**

```
public interface INewPageService
{
     void  CreateNewPage();
}
```

**Implement**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(INewPageService))]

namespace BlankApp1.UWP
{
   public class INewPageServiceImplement : INewPageService
    {
        public async void CreateNewPage()
        {
            CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
            int newViewId = 0;
            await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Frame frame = new Frame();
                frame.Navigate(typeof(NewPage)); // uwp page
                Window.Current.Content = frame;
                // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
                Window.Current.Activate();

                newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
            });
            bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);

         }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
DependencyService.Get<INewPageService>(DependencyFetchTarget.NewInstance).CreateNewPage();
```

Please don't forget register it in uwp app.xaml.cs file.

```
if (rootFrame == null)
{
    // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
    rootFrame = new Frame();

    rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);
    DependencyService.Register<INewPageService, INewPageServiceImplement>();
    if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
    {
        //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
    }

    // Place the frame in the current Window
    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail solution. What about the another issue about scrren capture? Could you reproduce the screen capture issue?

Comment: I checked but I could not reproduce your issue, please check your company policy that if lock the outlook capture capability.

Comment: Currently, I test my own pc which is 1903, still get this issue.

Comment: Please check this [screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJooD.png)   and it works well in my side.

Comment: Could you try to make a test with computer is 1906 or lower instead of 1909?

Comment: Well, I need to find the lower version computer, I will give the result tomorrow.